# Getting 100K visitor per day on Blogger.com based site will be slow or Bandwidth disturb or site will be down?

Tags: web-services, web, web-deployment, blogger, traffic

I am planning to launch a blogging Site, only for blogging. So I don't need any funtionality in the site. That's why as a begineer I selected Blogger.com. I will post there Continusly and regularly. So before launch I have a Question, "If my Blog get 100K pageviews per day, Will it be Slow or Bandwidth problem? my site will be down?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Blogger.com is ran by Google, so I don't expect it to have any trouble.